Windows Server 2022 - How to enable / configure RDP? Remote Desktop Session Host is not configured
I can't RDP onto a Windows 2022 server.
I can see a warning that the Remote Desktop Session Host server is not configured and that a grace period for allowing this has expired. So the issue is due to RDP setup and not network/ports. When I try to RDP I get this message on successful authentication:

Your session ended because the remote PC isn't licensed to accept remote connections. Ask your admin or tech support for help.
Error code: 0x2056
Extended error code: 0x257

The server is a standalone server, not a domain controller. The RD Licensing Diagnoser says I have 0 number of licenses available for clients. How do I configure the server to accept RDP connections? I just need this to manage the server.

Remove the RDS roles from the server.

WHAT RDP? Terminal server (RDS role) or for administration? THe later one allows only admins, 2 max and - cough - has no licensing issues.

Only need RDP for administration not as a terminal server.

Thanks @joeqwerty - removing RDS roles has fixed it

Fixed by removing the Remote Desktop Service roles from the server. This is not required when you only need maximum 2 logins for server admin.
